# How can I generate data for groups of numbers between zeroes in a column in a 2D array?

Tags: c

Say, I have this 2D array of integers:

```
0 0 1 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 2 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 3 3 2 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0
```

How can I generate data for the columns, based on how many numbers are between one or more zeroes?
Like this for example:

```
0
0
1-1-1 1 1 1
4-1-2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1
2-1-5 1 1 1 2 1 2 3 2
1-3-2 1 1 1 1 3 2
2-1 2 1 2 
1 1
0
0
```

Where a space of zeroes between numbers is designated by a "-".

So "4-1-2" means there are four non-zero numbers, then zeroes, then one non-zero number, then zeroes, then two non-zero numbers.

I came up with this, but I don't know where I'm failing:

```
int ColumnData[size][size+1][size+1];

for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
{
    int GroupsCount = 1;
    int ValueCount = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        int value = map[y][x];

        if (value == 0)
        {
            ValueCount = 0;
            GroupsCount += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ValueCount += 1;
            ColumnData[y][GroupsCount][ValueCount] = value;
        }
    }

    ColumnData[y][0][0] = GroupsCount;
    ColumnData[y][GroupsCount][0] = ValueCount;
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    int Groups_Count = ColumnData[i][0][0];

    for (int j = 1; j <= Groups_Count; j++)
    {
        int Values_Count = ColumnData[i][j][0];

        printf("%d", Values_Count);
        if (Groups_Count != 1 || j == Groups_Count)  // not the beginning or last
        {
            printf("-");
        }
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= Groups_Count; j++)
    {
        int Values_Count = ColumnData[i][j][0];
        for (int k = 1; k <= Values_Count; k++)
        {
            int Value = ColumnData[i][j][k];
            printf(" %d", Values_Count);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Why are you manipulating a 3D array `ColumnData` instead of just iterating your 2D array columnwise and using a counter?

Comment: Can you phrase this algorithm in plain language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you need simply by iterating your 2D array in a columnwise manner and keeping track of the state. (whether values found, the number of non-zero values in sequence) and a second array to store the found values for later output after your `x-x-x` code.

You simply need to pay attention to how the output is done to avoid stay `'-'` where it need not be, etc..

You can do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLS  10
#define ROWS  COLS

int main (void) {
    
    int arr[][COLS] = {{0,0,1,2,1,1,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,1,1,1,2,1,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,1,3,3,2,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0}};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {                    /* loop each col */
        int first = 1,                                  /* flag 1st output */
            found = 0,                                  /* no. vals found */
            n = 0,                                      /* no. vals in seq. */
            values[ROWS] = {0};                         /* capture values */
        for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {                /* loop each row */
            if (!arr[j][i]) {                           /* element zero */
                if (n) {                                /* vals in seq? */
                    printf (first ? "%d" : "-%d", n);   /* output no. in seq */
                    first = n = 0;                      /* reset flags */
                }
            }
            else {  /* number found */
                values[found++] = arr[j][i];            /* add to values array */
                n++;                                    /* update seq. cnt */
            }
        }
        /* if sequence includes last row */
        if (n) {                                        /* vals in seq? */
            printf (first ? "%d" : "-%d", n);           /* output no. in seq */
            first = n = 0;                              /* reset flags */
        }
        if (!found)                                     /* nothing found */
            putchar ('0');                              /* output 0 */
        for (int k = 0; k < found; k++)                 /* otherwise loop */
            printf (" %d", values[k]);                  /* outputting values */
        putchar ('\n');                                 /* tidy up with \n */
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/columnstats
0
0
1-1-1 1 1 1
4-1-2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1
2-7 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 3 2
1-3-2 1 1 1 1 3 2
1-1 2 2
1 1
0
0
```

Which looks like what you need. (although there are two rows that differ, but based on your description of the algorithm -- this output should be the correct output) For example, your fifth column which corresponds to the fifth line of output is:

```c
    int arr[][COLS] = {{ , , , ,1, , , , },
                       { , , , ,1, , , , },
                       { , , , ,0, , , , },
                       { , , , ,1, , , , },
                       { , , , ,1, , , , },
                       { , , , ,2, , , , },
                       { , , , ,1, , , , },
                       { , , , ,2, , , , },
                       { , , , ,3, , , , },
                       { , , , ,2, , , , }};
```

According to your problem description that is a code of `2-7` (sequence of 2 numbers, zeros, sequence of 7 numbers) followed by the values `1 1 1 1 2 1 2 3 2` which would make the total line of output:

```
2-7 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 3 2
```

instead of what your example output gives:

```
2-1-5 1 1 1 2 1 2 3 2
```

This because there is no sequence of 2 digits, zeros, a single digit, zeros, followed by 5 more digits in the column.

Double check this discrepancy and let me know what you have found.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This answer is nearly perfect. But if for example, there were no zeroes in a row (so there's 10 values), it would not print the first number in the line which would be "10", only the following values.

Comment: Then change the `if (value == 0)` line.

Comment: It is perfect now, he edited it. Thank you